# Web starter kit installation Error

Tags: ruby, node.js, gwt, web

when i run the installation process and put npm install in the command line after running some processes it gives me this :

```
npm ERR! safefs@3.0.6 preinstall: `node ./cyclic.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the safefs@3.0.6 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the safefs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./cyclic.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls safefs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
```

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Class Talkies\Desktop\www\web-starter-kit-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Answer (score 0):

I also got a few errors upon installing via the `npm install` command, but in order to get it to go away I relaunched command prompt in administrator mode. It solved the problem easily.

Hope it helps!